# Agregar Imagen a Botón de Formulario. mas función de verificación

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen

si quiero cambiar el botón de ENVIAR (submit). por una imagen. se puede Hacer? intente poner la imagen pero no me funciono. alli les deje el código abajo.

y otra cosita colegas. para que el botón no se active hasta colocar el nombre. como hago? me refiero a que si la persona no coloca el nombre. el botón no te permita irte a whatsapp y te diga que tienes que colocar el nombre.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<head>
<script>
   function setNombre() {
    var miUrl = " https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=584144416340&text=%21Hola%21%20Quiero%20Informacion%20de%20el%20Curso%20Whastapp.%20Soy%20" + document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
    window.open(miUrl);
               
   }
  </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <input id="txtNombre" type="text" name="fname" required placeholder="Tu Nombre" size="30" maxlength="10" /><br>
  
  <button id="btnWAPP" type="image" src="https://marketingcongabrielguzman.ga/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/WPSOL-1.png" onclick="setNombre()">Pedir mi curso por Whastapp</button>
```

Gracias a Todos de antemano.

la idea es agregar una comprobació JS asi:

```js
if(txtNombre === ""){alert("Debes Colocar Tu Nombre"); return false;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cesar, bienvenido a la comunidad, intenta con este código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="txtNombre" type="text" name="fname" required placeholder="Tu Nombre" size="30" maxlength="10" onchange="activateButton(this.value)"/><br>

<input id="btnWhatsApp" type="image" src="https://marketingcongabrielguzman.ga/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/WPSOL-1.png" onclick="setNombre()" disabled=true/>
<script>

function activateButton(val){
    if(val !== null && val !== ''){
        //Activar botón
        document.getElementById("btnWAPP").disabled = false;
    }
};
function setNombre(val) {
  var miUrl = " https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=584144416340&text=%21Hola%21%20Quiero%20Informacion%20de%20el%20Curso%20Whastapp.%20Soy%20" + document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
  window.open(miUrl);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Después de llenar el nombre en el campo txtNombre, debes hacer click fuera del campo y el botón estará activo para enviar el mensaje mediante WhatsApp.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: hola amigo ValVert gracias por ayudarme. use tu cogigo. pero al colocar el nombre el boton no se activa. [te dejo aqui la pagina web donde estoy probando el codigo](https://marketingcongabrielguzman.ga/elementor-146/) q crees que este fallando colega?

Comment: Estimado, verifica el nombre del input y la corroboración del mismo. El nombre en ambos debiese ser `btnWAPP`

Comment: amigo valvert lo que esta bloquando el boton es el . disabled="true" sera alli el error mi amigo? y por eso no se activa el boton

Comment: @CesarGabrielGuzman lo que solicitaste es que cuando el texto contenga un nombre se active el botón de Whatsapp. Por lo tanto el botón parte deshabilitado (es por eso que `disabled="true"`), cuando el usuario llena el nombre hay una función que lo activa (`document.getElementById("btnWAPP").disabled = false;`).

Comment: mi hermano lo coloque todo como me dices pero el boton no se activa. que crees que este faltando? sera mi pagina web?

Comment: listo mi amigo @valvert el error fue el que me dijiste el ID  de document.getElementById("btnWAPP") estaba errado era document.getElementById("btnWhatsApp").

Comment: @CesarGabrielGuzman me alegro, éxito con tu emprendimiento.

Comment: mi hermano y si coloco esta funcion? <script>
function validar(){
 var txtNombre, miUrl;
    txtNombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
    miUrl = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=584144416340&text=%21Hola%21%20Quiero%20Informacion%20de%20el%20Curso%20Whastapp.%20Soy%20" + document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
  window.open(miUrl);
    
    if (txtNombre === ""){
    alert("Coloca Tu Nombre");
        return false;
    }
                   }
   </script>

Comment: para que en vez de bloquear el boton. deje q valide si hay nombre y si no hay q mande una alerta. de que debe colocar el nombre. <input id="btnWhatsApp" type="image" src="https://marketingcongabrielguzman.ga/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/WPSOL-1.png" onclick="return validar();"

Comment: @CesarGabrielGuzman Serviría también, pero te recomiendo que trabajes el  _if_

Comment: mi hermano ayudame porfa. no soy muy experto. https://marketingcongabrielguzman.ga/elementor-146/ alli deje el codigo que utilice. funciona pero no evita q abra el link asi este vacio. q le puedo agregar? para q no abra el link si el campo esta vacio? es lo unico que me hace falta

Comment: no quiero q se desabilite, solo quiero q mande la alerta de que falte el nombre. y que el link no abra. q puedo hacer? q puedo agregar

Comment: que abra el link solo si se cumple este  if (txtNombre === ""){
    alert("Coloca Tu Nombre");
        return false;

Comment: Resuelto. le coloque un Else. y meti el link dentro de el

Answer (score 0):

Para el boton con la imagen puedes crear una etiqueta de link `<a>` y le agregas la imagen

```
<a href="#"><img src="https://marketingcongabrielguzman.ga/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/WPSOL-1.png"></a>
```

Luego le das los estilos con css.

Comment: amigo es lo que pasa es que este boton es de un formulario que ejecuta una funcion en javascript. echele un vistazo al codigo. para q veas la funcion que cumple.  <button id="btnWAPP" type="image" src="https://marketingcongabrielguzman.ga/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/WPSOL-1.png" onclick="setNombre()">Pedir mi curso por Whastapp</button>